# self-organizing map in R produces one big cluster and several small clusters

Tags: r, machine-learning, hierarchical-clustering

I am currently doing some work for a charity. I use a self-organising map to cluster donors in R. This is the R code I am currently using:

```
library(dplyr)
library(kohonen)

setwd('d:\\Bla')

OrginalData <- read.table("InputForSom1.txt",
                   header = TRUE, sep = "\t")

SubsetData <- subset(OrginalData, select = c(
"Frequency2013" 
,"Sum2013"  
,"Frequency2014"    
,"Sum2014"  
,"Frequency2015"    
,"Sum2015"  
,"Frequency2016"    
,"Sum2016"  
,"Frequency2017"    
,"Sum2017"
#,"Easting"
#,"Northing"
))
TrainingMatrix <- as.matrix(scale(SubsetData))
#TrainingMatrix <- as.matrix(SubsetData)

GridDefinition <- somgrid(xdim = 10, ydim = 10, topo = "rectangular")

SomModel <- kohonen::supersom(data = TrainingMatrix, grid = GridDefinition, rlen = 1000, alpha = c(0.05, 0.001),
             keep.data = TRUE)
groups = 3
tree.hc = cutree(hclust(dist(SomModel$codes[[1]])), groups)

plot(SomModel, type = "codes", bgcol = rainbow(groups)[tree.hc])
add.cluster.boundaries(SomModel, tree.hc)

result <- OrginalData
result$Cluster <- tree.hc[SomModel$unit.classif]
result$X <- SomModel$grid$pts[SomModel$unit.classif,"x"]
result$Y <- SomModel$grid$pts[SomModel$unit.classif,"y"]

write.table(result, file = "SomOutput.csv", sep = ",", col.names = NA,
            qmethod = "double")
```

For each donor I know how often (s)he donated in a year and the total yearly amount. Please note, that I could also generate more fine grained data (i.e. monthly donations and monthly totals). I also know the donor’s spatial location in UK’s easting in northings (see subset statement above). 
The problem I have is that the ‘tree.hc part’ of the code produces one massive cluster (containing almost all donors) and several very small clusters. Is there a way to obtain more equally distributed clusters?

Comment: Two potentially useful diagnostics: use hierarchical clustering (`hclust` from `cluster` package) to help visualize clusters. If cluster breakdown is similar, you might get some insight into the structure. Second, subset your data to include only the units in the mega cluster, then run the SOM.

Comment: Thanks. I subset the data already as a first attempt. Could you possibly share some hierarchical clustering code please?

Comment: You need distance matrix as input to `?hclust` function e.g `hc = hclust(dist(mtcars[,-1]));plot(hc)`  and [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/hierarchical-clustering-essentials-unsupervised-machine-learning) for more examples.